# Intuitive explanation of insulated boundary condition

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, boundary-conditions, heat-conduction

Could someone please provide an intuitive explanation of why an insulated end of a rod must have a temperature gradient $\frac{dT}{dx}$ equal to zero? Based on the [previous question I asked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/652214/), it seems that if the left end of a rod is insulated, this end must always have the same temperature as the point immediately to the right of it but I can't make sense of why that has to be.

Comment: The temperature gradient being equal to zero at the end of the rod does not necessarily mean that the temperature at a point a short distance in from the end is exactly the same as at the end.  The second derivative will not necessarily be zero.  So the temperature profile is going to be like a parabola, with a maximum or minimum at the very end.  This is what zero heat flux means.  When the temperature gradient is zero at the end, it means that the rate of heat flow into or out of the rod at that location is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take two finite elements that are next to each other along the $x$ axis, with one at a temperature $T_1$ and the other at temperature $T_2$, then heat will flow from one element to the other if they are at different temperatures. So if there is no heat flow between the elements then they must be at the same temperature i.e. $\delta T = T_2 - T_1 = 0$.

If we let the size of the elements $\delta x$ approach zero then in the limit we have

$$\displaystyle \frac {dT}{dx} = \lim_{\delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\delta T}{\delta x}=0$$

if there is no heat flow at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought that the rod being insulated at the end meant that there is no heat flow from the *surroundings* to the element at the end of the rod. I didn't think it meant that there is no heat flow between elements *within* the rod. Am I incorrect?

Comment: The condition $\frac {dT}{dx}=0$ applies at *any* point where there is no heat flow in the $x$ direction - it doesn't matter whether this point is at at an end of the rod or within the rod. There is nothing intrinsically special about end points (except for the fact that we are usually given constraints or "boundary conditions" that apply at such points).

Comment: Then does $\frac{dT}{dx}=0$ at the end imply that the temperature of the surroundings must be at the same temperature as the end of the rod so that there's no heat transfer from surroundings to the end of the rod?

Comment: @sl2outnow Yes - unless the insulation is $100 \%$ efficient, which is only theoretically possible. At the end of the day, I think you just have to accept that “insulated” is shorthand for “no heat flow” which in turn means $\frac {dT}{dx}=0$ at the ends of the rod.

Comment: The temperature of the surroundings at the end of the rod is always equal to the rod temperature at the end, irrespective of whether the surroundings represent insulation.  Temperature between the two media is continuous.

Comment: Right. Thank you for the correction. I meant to ask if the temperature gradient would have to approach zero as you approached from the surroundings to the interface between the surroundings and the rod in order to have no heat flux at the boundary. Is that right?

Comment: It all depends on the scale of analysis. When we use Newton's law, with a heat transfer coefficient, we consider that there is a temperature discontinuity. Even if by returning to a finer scale, we would find that the temperature varies very quickly over a very thin layer.