# Insulated boundary heat problem with rigor

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider the following heat problem:
\begin{align*}
u_t &= u_{xx}\\
u_x(0,t) &= u_x(1, t) = 0\\
u(x,0) &= g(x)
\end{align*}

This problem apparently corresponds to a 1D rod that is insulated at the boundary, with initial heat distribution $g$.

While intuitively I understand this, I would like to find a reference that would justify why it truly makes sense to approximate this physical problem by the equation specified above, by some slightly more rigorous approach. This question [Intuitive explanation of insulated boundary condition](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/652590/intuitive-explanation-of-insulated-boundary-condition) gives some ideas, but I'm still not completely convinced.

**What I don't understand** - if a segment of the rod has no heat flowing into it at any time, this implies the temperature is constant. Translating this into a continuous setting - $u_x(0, t) = 0$ for all $t$ implies $u(0,t)$ is constant - if there's no heat flowing into $0$ at any time, then the temperature of $0$ never changes. Thus when trying to describe our heat problem in continuous mathematical setting, it seems to me like we can also add the condition of $u(0,t), u(1,t)$ being constant, and so the problem really is
\begin{align*}
u_t &= u_{xx}\\
u_x(0,t) &= u_x(1, t) = 0\\
u(0,t) &= g(0)\\
u(1,t) &= g(1)\\
u(x,0) &= g(x)
\end{align*}
i.e. we Dirichlet boundary condition problem (and the $u_x$ condition is redundant).

Now I know there's something wrong about this, but I can't quite see what it is.

**Why does it make sense to describe the property of "insulated from the left" by $u_x(0,t) = 0$ ?** Intuitively, I don't fully understand why insulation would force any sort of behavior on the slope of the temperature IN the rod. It would make much more sense to me to say that "insulated from the left" implies that the derivative from the left is $0$, but that's not the same thing.

For example, what if you have a rod with an initial temperature distribution that does not have a $0$ derivative at the boundary points? That seems like physically possible situation, but it can't really be described as a heat equation with boundary conditions of $u_x(0, t) = u_x(1,t) = 0$. How would you translate such a problem to a mathematical setting?

Comment: If the beam material obeys $u_t=u_{xx}$ (that is, if the thermal diffusivity in these units is 1), then setting the thermal diffusivity to something other than 1 within the bar isn’t “more rigorous,” it’s just wrong. This is the implication of $k\neq 1$ within this region $\delta$ that you’ve defined.

Comment: In a medium with thermal conductivity $k$, the heat flux is $Q = k u_x$. The heat equation is then just the conservation equation $$u_t = Q_x= k u_{xx} + k_x u_x$$ The differential operators $D^{(k)}u = (ku_x)_x$ are self-adjoint. Taking the limit $\delta \to 0$ seem to involve studying the continuity of their Green function (or alternatively of the exponential operators $\exp(tD^{(k)})$) with respect to $k$. I am not competent enough in functional analysis to do this properly.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I'm not sure what your point is - if it's wrong, and taking the limit $\delta \rightarrow 0$ is not justified, would you point out why it's not?

Comment: @Chemomechanics Anyway, I'm not sure how the first equation is correct as far as describing the physical example - if you consider the boundary of the rod to be a part of the rod, and there's no flow into it, then its temperature is constant too. It seems to me like there's something fishy going on when we describe the physical problem with the boundary condition of $u_x(0, t) = 0$, as this should in some sense imply that $u(0,t) = 0$ also.

Comment: It doesn’t imply that in any way. A slope of zero doesn’t imply a magnitude of zero, or, put another way, a great many horizontal lines don’t pass through the origin.

Comment: In any case, you’re free to solve the more general problem using $\delta$ and then let $\delta\to 0$ or simply plug in $\delta=0$ to recover the solution for the original problem. That’s not more rigorous or even necessary, it’s just more general.

Comment: Do you have a problem with the concept that the ends of the rod are thermally insulated?

Comment: What do you think the temperature distribution looks like at long times?

Comment: @Chemomechanics I'm assuming an initial value condition of $0$.

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes, I do. Take any fixed, "infinitesimal" part of the rod. If there is no flow into this part, the temperature is of this part is constant right? In a continuous setting, denoting the "segment" by $x_0$, does this not translate to: $u_x(x_0, t) = 0$ implies $u(x_0, t)$ is constant?

Comment: *”I'm assuming an initial value condition of 0.”* That’s not what your question says. It gives the initial profile as $g(x)$.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Sorry you're right, I should have specified $g(0)=g(1)=0$, regardless the idea is the same - I've made a comment to ChetMiller that describes what I mean.

Comment: An initial profile of $g(x)=x^2$ on $(0, \frac{1}{2})$ and $(1-x)^2$ on $(\frac{1}{2},1)$ , for example, satisfies all the conditions you’ve given.  There are an infinite number of other examples. The steady-state temperature is always the average of $g(x)$. Please consider editing your question to clarify.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I've edited the question, removed my own thoughts/approaches, and instead tried to clarify what exactly I find confusing. Please let me know if the question is now more understandable.

Comment: $x_0$ is not a segment of the rod.  It is a cross sectional location along the rod...a point.  A segment of the rod is the region $\Delta x$ between x and $x+\Delta x$.  If the rate of heat flow in at x differs from the rate of heat flow out at $x+\Delta x$, the temperature within $\Delta x$ will be changing with time.  So the rate of heat flow at a location $x_0$ equal to zero (as implied by $u_x(x_0,t)=0) $ does not imply anything about $u(x_0,t)$, let alone that it is equal to zero.

Comment: @Jake1234 Thanks, I’ve voted to reopen because the conceptual issue is now clear: The premise “…if a segment of the rod has no heat flowing into it at any time…” is incorrect. An insulated boundary condition means that no heat flows in or out of **one end** of the edge infinitesimal element. Heat can still flow in or out of the other end of that element, changing the element’s temperature as mediated by its heat capacity. This can be more fully explained in an answer.

Comment: @ChetMiller Oh of course, the rate of change of the temperature is related to the integral over the boundary, I get it. I think I implicitly assumed that if $u_x(x_0) = 0$, I can take a sufficiently small neighborhood of $x_0$ on which it's constant, but that doesn't make sense.